# Python - sum element by element JSON dicitonaries

Tags: python

I have list, with 2 sub-lists. Each sub-list has two list of JSON dictionaries. Something like that:

```
[
  [
    {'type': 'a', 'id': 1, 'values': [1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.3]}, 
    {'type': 'a', 'id': 2, 'values': [29, 25, 21, 22]},
  ], 
  [
    {'type': 'a', 'id': 3, 'values': [6.36, 6.58, 6.62, 6.66 ]}, 
    {'type': 'a', 'id': 4, 'values': [1.2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5]},
  ]
]
```

I would like to get the sum of 'values' element by element for each sub-list:

```
output=[[30, 26, 21.5, 22.3 ],[7.56, 8.08, 8.02, 8.16 ]]
```

do you know how to do it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input list is named `json_list`, you can use a list comprehension:

```
output = [list(map(sum, zip(*(d['values'] for d in l)))) for l in json_list]
```

output:

```
[[30.0, 26.0, 21.5, 22.3], [7.5600000000000005, 8.08, 8.120000000000001, 8.16]]
```

Alternatively:

```
output = [[round(sum(x), 2) for x in zip(*(d['values'] for d in l))]
          for l in json_list]
```

output:

```
[[30.0, 26.0, 21.5, 22.3], [7.56, 8.08, 8.12, 8.16]]
```

Comment: shouldn't use `json` as it is the name of the package you import

Comment: @GáborFekete it did hesitate when I wrote the answer, I went for simplicity, here it is ;)

Comment: anyway, I had another name used!